# Powering 150 WS2812B LED strips

Tags: arduino-uno

I just bought an Elegoo Uno R3 today and delved into programming Arduinos. For my first project I'd like to power a 5m LED strip (30 LED/m). I've learned that an individual neopixel needs around 60 mA, and i'm gonna assume this means that to power all 150, I need 9A. I'm extremely new to all this (and electrical stuff in general) and not exactly sure how to go on about giving 9A worth of power to the strips and the Arduino. Any help to get me on the right track would be appreciated.

Comment: Step one: buy a power supply that gives *at least* 9A. Step two: connect it.

Comment: The neopixel uberguide should give all info required to get started. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjQss2n6-bgAhUBIVAKHQtlAFUQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1-UNr6xUSFV5fscJPYqsFR

Comment: "Any help to get me on the right track would be appreciated." Is not really a question. Notable is that this only counts if you put R/G/B all on 100%, you're right, but you may settle for less

Answer (score 2):

Your math looks right to me. You need a 9A power supply if you're going to drive all 150 LEDs at %100 brightness on all 3 channels.

I'd suggest using a separate 500mA 5V regulated power supply for the Arduino. Switching 9A of load on and off on the LED power supply is going to cause quite a bit of variation in the voltage on that 9A supply, and the simplest way to keep the power supply to the Arduino clean is to make the 2 power supplies completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the power supply in multiple places to the LED strip. The two ends and the middle at least. That will keep all the current from having to flow thru all of the strip.  If try to power it from just one end, the power traces in the strip might act as a fuse and blow open. Or it might survive, but act like a low-ohm resistor and the chips farther down the string will see less voltage (because voltage down the trace = current x resistance) and may appear dim, or act weirdly, or not turn on at all.

Comment: I would hope that an off-the-shelf LED strip is built with heavy-duty enough traces to handle it's maximum current load. If not is a pretty shoddy product, an would likely fail UL or CE test certification.

Comment: Do you see any UL or CE test certification marking on your strip?

Comment: Fair question, but even if they aren't UL/CE certified, they shouldn't melt if you turn everything on.

Comment: Yes, "shouldn't". But very hot is not melting, yet can still have lots of voltage loss down the length. Measure the voltage down the string if you see odd things.